# Once a document is posted to Solr, how quickly is it available for searching?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm seeking a little advice on a proposed architecture with Solr.

Our documents will be XML and probably (25kb-100kb) a piece. We will be two streams of documents. One is the core stream, which will receive of 15-60 documents per second. Once a documents arrives on the core stream, it needs to be searchable within 2 hours. Another stream is a priority stream which will have only 200-500 per day, but the documents on this stream will need to be searchable within 1-25 seconds.

If it matters, we plan to run this on modest commodity hardware (raid6 over normal sata drives, dual core xeon, 8gb ram).

Are our proposed SLAs within easy reach or will we need enterprise class hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once a document is posted to Solr, how quickly is it available for searching?

As soon as it is committed and the new IndexSearcher is available.

You may be interested in the [commitWithin option of the add command](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22) to make sure that the document you're adding will be searchable within the specified time.

How long the commit takes depends on a number of factors: autowarming, mergeFactor...